# lattices in semisimple Lie groups

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, coxeter-groups, lattices-in-lie-groups

I would like to learn more on lattices in semisimple Lie groups, especially their relations with Coxeter groups. Does anyone have suggestions of books that could be useful?

Thanks!

Comment: Wikipedia's page on [Lattices in Lie Groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_%28group%29) suggests Conway & Sloane's "Sphere Packings, Lattices and Groups". However, that's probably not too helpful. Humphreys has a different book on Coxeter groups (which is a good read) but it doesn't include connections to Lie groups (as far as I remember). If you don't get any better responses here, you might try http://mathoverflow.net Jim Humphreys logs in regularly and would certainly have some good suggestions.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_%28discrete_subgroup%29#References) also mentions the book [Margulis: Discrete Subgroups of Semisimple Lie Groups](http://books.google.com/books?id=V9z2cjHOhVoC), perhaps you find there something which would be interesting for you.

Comment: It was suggested in a moderator flag that this question be migrated to MathOverflow. Just wanted to explain that MathOverflow is not a part of the SE 2.0 network ([or at least, not yet](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1082/migrate-to-se-20)), so question migration is not possible - it would have to be reposted by hand.

Answer (score 2):

I realize that this is a very old post, still here is an answer:

1. If you want to understand (connected) semisimple Lie groups, then indeed you have to learn a bit about *finite* Coxeter groups first, since they are closely tied to the root systems. For that, say, Bourbaki's "Lie Groups and Lie Algebras" or Humphreys "Introduction to Lie algebras and representation theory" are good references (there are many other sources).
2. If you want to understand lattices in semisimple Lie groups, then, *indirectly*, you see their relation to finite Coxeter groups. There are several books dealing with lattices in semisimple Lie groups, the gentlest one, I think, is [Introduction to Arithmetic Groups](http://deductivepress.ca/) by Dave Witte Morris. You can also read Zimmer's book [Ergodic theory and semisimple groups](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780817631840) or Raghunathan's book 
   "Discrete subgroups of Lie groups" (both are still reasonably gentle); the hardest one to read will be the most important one, by Margulis
   "Discrete Subgroups of Semisimple Lie Groups" mentioned by Bill Cook in his comment.
3. After spending few years going through these books you may suddenly remember that you were interested in lattices in connection to Coxeter groups and you find **almost nothing** about Coxeter groups in these sources. This is due to the following:

**Theorem.** If $\Gamma$ is a Coxeter group isomorphic to a lattice in a simple noncompact Lie group $G$, then $G$ is (locally) isomorphic to $O(n,1)$ for some $n$. (In fact, you can replace simple with semisimple, then $G$ will be locally isomorphic to a product of $O(n_i,1)$'s.)

Proof. Unless $G$ is locally isomorphic to $SO(n,1)$ or $SU(n,1)$, it has Kazhdan's Property T (whatever it is), hence, every lattice in $G$ has property T, but infinite finitely generated Coxeter  groups never have Property T. Lastly, lattices in $SU(n,1)$ were shown not to be isomorphic to Coxeter groups in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.1493.pdf) by Pierre Py (actually, he proves more). qed

Thus, there is *almost* no connection between Coxeter groups and lattices except for a negative one. That is, except for the fact that many nice examples of lattices in $O(n,1)$ (for small $n$) are indeed  given by Coxeter groups. See for instance my answer to [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1393561/easy-examples-of-non-arithmetic-lattices/1528620#1528620). Well, actually, there is more to this story, since, according to theorems by Vinberg and Prokhorov, there are no reflection subgroups in $O(n,1)$ which are lattices, provided that $n\ge 997$. Thus, **most likely**, groups $O(n,1)$, $n\ge 1000$, contain no lattices which are isomorphic to Coxeter groups.