# Example of a cocompact lattice in SL(2,R)

Tags: differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, lattices-in-lie-groups

I would like to understand compact hyperbolic manifolds a bit better. Hyperbolic manifolds may be described as quotients of hyperbolic space by a torsion-free, discrete subgroup (lattice) of the isometry group $\mathrm{PO}(n,1)$.

Let us start in dimension 2. I would like to study a compact quotient of the hyperbolic plane $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})/\mathrm{SO}(2)$ as a toy example. That means I need a cocompact lattice $\Gamma\subset\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$.

Does anyone know an example?

By §XII.1, Thm. 3 in Lang's book $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$, $\Gamma$ may not contain nontrivial unipotent elements. That means it cannot simply be an extension of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ because this one already contains, for example, the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: See Example 4 and Example 7 in Benoist's lecture [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjk7MSeufWAAxXmhP0HHUe9DGwQFnoECBIQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbremy.perso.math.cnrs.fr%2Fsmf_sec_18_04.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1rjy8AWZWefaIcSRCOl1Ip&opi=89978449), page $12$.

Comment: See also examples in my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1393561/easy-examples-of-non-arithmetic-lattices/1528620#1528620), just make sure that $r<\infty$ to get cocompact lattices.

Comment: For a method of constructing many examples, look up the Poincare polygon theorem.